# Marked / selected / Highlighted text to Upper or Lower case jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, uppercase, lowercase

can someone help me, how to transform marked text in contenteditable div to Lower or Upper case on btn click via jQuery? Thanks for any response.

`<button type="button" id="asd" class="btn btn-info" onclick="replaceSelectedText(window.getSelection().toString().toUpperCase())">toUpper</button>`

```
<script>
function replaceSelectedText(replacementText) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(replacementText));
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.text = replacementText;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Marked how? In your text field?

Comment: what you had done yet share your code

Comment: [Read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I do not get it, why u gave to me minus point...This question is simply readable..

Comment: @HonzíkAzjolHavelka Check my answer. May be it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
function replaceSelectedText(_this) {
    
    var sel, range;
     var selectedText=window.getSelection().toString();
    if ($.trim(selectedText)!="") {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            if($(_this).html().toString().toUpperCase()=="TOUPPER"){
            range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(selectedText.toString().toUpperCase()));
            $(_this).html("toLower");
            }
            else{
            range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(selectedText.toString().toLowerCase()));
            $(_this).html("toUpper");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>


<button type="button" id="asd" class="btn btn-info" onclick="replaceSelectedText(this)">toUpper</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make selected text to uppercase in content editable div. Check this jsfiddle

```
[0] http://jsfiddle.net/jignesh221290/7kmb2fm2/
```

For html tag you have to manage.